# How to display a breadcrumb from root the category to the product's category in laravel 7

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-7, laravel-relations

**Goal:**

On my product's detail page I want to display a breadcrumb of all the parent categories that my product has.

For example, if there is a product that is assigned a category_id pointing to a SubSubCategory; I want the breadcrumb to be:

```
Root Category / SubCategory / SubSubCategory
```

**Problem:**

Some products might a category_id that points to the root category (has no children) and other products might have a category_id that points to a category that is 2 levels deep (has two parents). How do I handle these scenarios?

**What I have tried:**

This is my [Category Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anCRh.png)

This is my [Categories table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1iHS.png)

So far, if I wanted to get the category breadcrumb of a specific product I would do it like this:

```
{{$product->category->parent->name}} / {{$product->category->name}}
```

But it quickly had errors with the products that had a root category assigned to them. Because I was trying to get a relationship that didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at that as behavior, meaning a method on the `product` and `category`. For instance:

```
{{ $product->trail() }}
```

In which the `product` knows how to compute it's own `category` breadcrumb trail.

First, to the category we give a method to compute it's own upstream parts of the trail.

```
$category = function(string $name, $parent = null) {
    return new class($name, $parent) {
        public $name;
        public $parent;

        public function __construct(string $name, $parent = null) {
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->parent = $parent;
        }

        public function breadcrumbs(array $trail = []) {
            $trail[] = $this->name;

            return $this->parent ? $this->parent->breadcrumbs($trail) : $trail;
        }
    };
};
```

Then from the product, we can ask it to compute it with a separator, giving us the trail in return.

```
$product = function(string $name, ...$categories) use($category) {
    $categories = array_reduce(array_reverse($categories), function($set, $item) use($category) {
        if (!$set) {
            return $category($item);
        }

        return $category($item, $set);
    });

    return new class($name, $categories) {
        public $name;
        public $categories;

        public function __construct(string $name, $categories) {
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->categories = $categories;
        }

        public function trail(string $separator = ' / '): string {
            return implode($separator, $this->categories->breadcrumbs());
        }
    };
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
$book = $product('Harry Potter', 'books', 'hardback', 'young-adult');
$shoes = $product('Air Jordans', 'shoes', 'mens', 'sports', 'basketball');
$tapeMeasure = $product('Stanley 25', 'hardware', 'tools', 'measurement');

var_dump(
    $book->trail(),        // books / hardback / young-adult
    $shoes->trail(),       // shoes / mens / sports / basketball
    $tapeMeasure->trail()  // hardware / tools / measurement
);
```

https://3v4l.org/FNKZI

And if you're looking for something a little more sophisticated, you can extend `$product->trail()` with a decorator.

```
public function linkSimilar(string $separator = ' / '): string {
    return $this->trail($separator, function(string $name) {
        return sprintf('<a href="/category/%s?similar-to=product/%s">%s</a>', $name, $this->sku, $name);
    });
}

...

$product->linkSimilar(' > ')
```

Providing:

```
<a href="/category/hardware?similar-to=product/U425263">hardware</a>
 > <a href="/category/tools?similar-to=product/U425263">tools</a>
 > <a href="/category/measurement?similar-to=product/U425263">measurement</a>
```

https://3v4l.org/22n15